# rentrez to retrieve NIH files

Tags: r, entrez

I'm trying to use rentrez package to retrieve NIH files, and ran the following code (I followed what was on the rentrez tutorial):

```
pubmed_search <- entrez_search(db = "pubmed", 
                    term = "Case Reports[Filter] AND cardiovascular disease AND English[lang] AND 2009:2019[PDat])", 
                    retmax = 792711, 
                    use_history = TRUE)

for(i in seq(1,10000,100)){   
    recs <- entrez_summary(db="pubmed", 
                           web_history=pubmed_search$web_history,
                           retmax=100, 
                           retstart=i)   cat(    
seq_start+99, "sequences downloaded\r") }
```

However, instead of the 10,000 texts I expected, I only downloaded 100 files. Could so

Comment: Welcome to Bioinformatics.SE! It looks like you posted the question before you were done typing. No worries, just use the `edit` button to update it. Also, please indent code with 4 spaces or wrap it in triple backticks (`\`\`\``) so that it displays in a legible way.

Comment: Also, include an API code in your Pubmed search script to increase the query limit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't program in R, but replace the last line of you code with the following and I suspect you will find it works,

```
for(i in seq(1,10000,1)){ recs <- entrez_summary(db="pubmed", web_history=pubmed_search$web_history, retmax=100, retstart=i) cat(seq_start+99, "sequences downloaded\r") }
```

**Rationale** I would guess `seq` is similar to the `linspace` function in Python, and put simply `10000 (total sample size) / 100 (the step size) = 100`, 100 being the number of downloads you observed. In the code above its `10000/1`. I would also suspect "step size = 1" is default, if this was correct then `seq(1,10000)` would give you your required output.

As a random aside I do like the presence of curly brackets defining the loop, it reminds me of Perl.